# How to combine a single regex group with multiple subsequent groups

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm modifying an existing Python script that extracts text from HTML schedules using regex. The script works great except for one situation which looks like this (greatly simplified):

```
<tr>
   <td class="month">September</td>
   <td class="date">1</td>
   <td class="date">8</td>
   <td class="date">15<td>
</tr>
```

I want to return:

```
('September', '1'),
('September', '8'),
('September', '15'),
```

...with a single regex.  Writing a regex to capture the groups is trivial.  I just can't figure out how to create the desired output with regex.  I've tried multiple combinations of lookaround, backreferences, etc.  I assume this is straightforward but just can't find the correct regex.  Any help is appreciated.

Also, I am fully aware that using regex on HTML text is not the best approach but this legacy system works well and just needs to handle this one case.

Similarly, I know I could return the individual groups and easily create the tuples in Python.  That kind of post-processing just doesn't fit well with the existing script.

Comment: You cannot do that with re. You may do something with PyPi regex module.

Comment: [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is much better at extracting information from HTML than attempting to do it with `regex`.

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for letting me know it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

`regex` is not recommended for trying to parse HTML. There will always be more than one "special case" that will trip up your expression. Even if the required output was possible in a single regex expression, the code would not be easy to maintain if the HTML changes at a later date.

It normal approach to such a problem would be to use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to do this. For the HTML you have provided, this could be done as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr>
   <td class="month">September</td>
   <td class="date">1</td>
   <td class="date">8</td>
   <td class="date">15</td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

month = soup.find('td', class_='month').text
dates = [(month, date.text) for date in soup.find_all('td', class_='date')]

print(dates)
```

This would display:

```
[('September', '1'), ('September', '8'), ('September', '15')]
```

Comment: As I said in the original post, I'm well aware that regex is not the best way to parse HTML.  I've used BeautifulSoup a lot.  Your answer was superfluous and not helpful.  Wiktor's answer was concise and answered the actual question.